# Cannot run rails commands due to possible error with .gemrc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, yaml, psych

When I type commands such as *"rails server"* or *"rails console"*,  I receive a large error message.

#### The error message

> > Failed to load /Users/user_name/.gemrc because it doesn't contain valid YAML hash

#### The trouble started when I ran these series of commands about an hour earlier.

> > sudo gem update --system
> > 9934  gem install gemcutter
> > 9935  gem tumble
> > 9936  gem update --system

Based on my research I am speculating that this has something to do with my **.gemrc** file which is currently blank.

I am out of my depth and would appreciate any assistance.

Thank you

Comment: Do share the versions of Ruby, Rails and Rubygems installed on your system.

Comment: I do now. I also just fixed the issue. Thank you for replying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I resolved the issue.

I did some additional research in the rdoc and found a solution.
I was placing the YAML file in the wrong user.

Thank you ##Kashyap.
I now understand the difference between system and user installations.